# Icon Not Appearing In MahApps RightWindowCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, icons, mahapps.metro

I started using mahapps a few days ago (still learning) and I tried to add an icon to the title bar, I did everything same as the example at their website and it won't appear. That's what I'm trying:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Rectangle Width="20"
               Height="20"
               Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_cog}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
        <Button Margin="4 0 0 0" Content="settings" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>`
```

And my app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.AnimatedTabControl.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/Icons.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

How can I make the icons appear? Here is an example of what I want it to look like: [image: What it should look like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Application31.MainWindow"
                  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                  xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
                  Icon="mahapps.metro.logo2.png"
                  BorderBrush="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  Title="MainWindow"
                  Height="350"
                  Width="350">

<Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>
    <Controls:WindowCommands>
        <Button>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="20"
                           Height="20"
                           Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}, Path=Foreground}">
                    <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource appbar_cog}" />
                    </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0">Settings</TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
    </Controls:WindowCommands>
</Controls:MetroWindow.RightWindowCommands>

<Grid>
    <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource AccentColorBrush}">
        <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
            <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill"
                         Visual="{StaticResource appbar_cog}" />
        </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

**App.xaml:**

```
<Application x:Class="MahApps.Metro.Application31.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro.Resources;component/Icons.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

[image]

---

**Notes:** for everything to work correctly you need to:

1) explicitly add `mahapps.metro.logo2.png` to your project;
2) explicitly add a project reference to `MahApps.Metro.Resources`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked, strange how placing it all in a button solved it

Answer (score 0):

Use `Icon` and `ShowIconOnTitleBar` and `ShowTitleBar` in your code, like this:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="MetroDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
        Title="My Application"
        Width="960" Height="600"
        Icon="mahapps.metro.logo2.ico"
        ShowIconOnTitleBar="True"
        ShowTitleBar="True">
    <Grid />
</Controls:MetroWindow>
```

---

**Edit:**
[Demo App](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/archive/master.zip)

Comment: @ShakedDahan, i suggest you to download MahApps demo app (i added it in the answer) and check your codes line by line. also check your icon file in the correct path. So i guess in this way you can easily find the problem and solve it. Please give me the feedback.

Comment: I already checked it, could it be something with my app flow direction being RightToLeft?

Comment: No, i used MahApp with both right to left and left to right. Check your icon (a `.ico` file). Also add the window `Xaml` properties in your question please.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the icon I'm talking about, I'm talking about this one: http://prntscr.com/curbm3